# Restrict Google+ Sign-In to specific Apps Domain

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-apps

Currently using the OAuth server side one-time-code flow, discussed here:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Works perfectly for google login.

I want the ability, though, to limit this login to only work for users that belong to a specific apps domain.

Is there any way to enforce this through the api?

OR am I limited to only doing this on my end after google authentication by regexing the email domain? (I would like to avoid this).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for doing this through Google login. We could allow a developer to set some restrictions on the client id if there are good use cases and a lot of developers would benefit with it. The primary issue I see with is the error message that we have to display to the user. It is better to display that error (and explain) on your site.

In general, as a good practice, you would always want to do the checks on your system/services regarding the authorized user (e.g. check domain)

Comment: I would add that a regex-based check is not always enough, because some Google Apps domains (mycompany.com) have subdomains (mysubsidiary.eu) and domain aliases (mycompany-oldname.com).
Most of the time you'll also want users with an email from a subdomain to be able to login.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this on the API is to use the fully server side flow (OpenID Connect).

The docs are here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect

With the parameter of interest here:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#hd-param

It doesn't appear to be possible with the server side one time code flow